# Synchronize a SharePoint (2013) list with Excel 2013

Tags: list, excel, synchronisation

I'm trying to synchronize data between a SharePoint list and Excel, and keep both sets of data up-to-date.

Data in excel get updated I want to update list and vice versa.
I have SharePoint 2013 and Office 2013 installed on my local system.
I want to active this OOTB task .

please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You specify you want this OOTB, but this is not possible out of the box since 2007, as Microsoft deprecated this feature (ability to sync bi-directionnaly a SharePoint list with an Excel file). OOTB Options include creating a new SP list from an Excel file and exporting a list to an Excel file.

To keep both data sets up to date, you need a third party tool such as [SharePoint List Synchronizer](https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com). Disclaimer: this product is edited by SoftFluent, my employer.